# Android Studio is not showing "Database Inspector" itself

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am using version 4.2, which is the latest version of Android Studio. As it says in the documentation, I searched for Database Inspector in "View -> Tool Windows" but it didn't appear there. How can I find Database Inspector, any help will be appriciated.

Thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

Comment: you have to run your app first, then go to view -> tools ,etc

Answer (score 5):

I just solved this, the flutter project was missing an Android module. Go to 'File -> Project Structure -> Modules'. Click on the '+' sign at the top to add a module. Select Android.

Comment: Great! Save my day (and almost four hours of google search....)